# Table search should wait for result

Tags: cypress

Hey guys and thanks for your attention!

Testcase: Im having a table and in this table i got a couple of settings i can search for via a search box!
I want to search for a setting name and as soon as it is found and shown as a single element in the table i want to click the "Edit" button in the last column of the table! There i can do some further changes.

Current issue: After i've entered the setting name in the search bar... cypress immediately clicks the "Edit" button for the first setting in the table. So it is not waiting for my searched setting is shown as the single element in the table!

I worked with a "wait" already... and it workd. But my boss is not happy with this solution!

So is there any other way to wait for the search to be finished?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Search is client side or server-side?

Comment: @Sree.Bh the search is server-side!

Comment: I had come across the exact same use case. I will add an answer with the approach I have used.

Comment: Perfect @Sree.Bh ... thank you very much in advance! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have added my approach. Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **client-side search**: you can try:

```
cy.get('input[type=search]').type(searchTerm).then(() => <expect_single_row>);
```

For **server-side search**: you can listen to the 'search' request and wait for the response to update the table:

```
function openSpecificRow(searchTerm) {
  search(searchTerm).then(() => {
    // if searchTerm is present in the row field
    cy.contains(searchTerm).parent('tr').siblings('.menu').click();
  });
}

function search(searchTerm) {
  cy.server();
  cy.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `/<url_path>?*&search=${searchTerm}*`
  }).as('searchResult');

  cy.get('input[type=search]').type(searchTerm);
  return cy.wait('@searchResult');
}
```

Note: Format the route url exactly the way it will be formed when search request will be triggered.

Comment: Your solution looks really good!
Thanks for that!

The issue is that in my case i don't get any XHR request when i search for the setting name!
So... nothing i could wait for!

Comment: So that means `search` is client side and in that case can you try: `cy.get('input[type=search]').type(searchTerm).then(() => <expect_single_row>)`

Comment: Happy to help :)